# Display and animate object in local axis

Tags: keyframes, coordinates

I would like to rotate an object along one on its local axis ; while I can do this via the viewport by selecting Local orientation, I would like to set keyframes using the Transform panel. However the transform panel always seems in World coordinates. How can I display (and hence keyframe) the Transform panel in local axis / coordinates ?

Comment: The transform, keyframed or not, *is* in local axes.  You may be misunderstanding what local axes are.  For an object that is unparented, they happen to be the same as world axes.  But imagine if you keyframed rotation, relative to the current direction that a face pointed (not the same thing): what is its unrotated rotation?  0.  Then rotate it-- now what is its rotation, relative to the current direction of a face?  It's still 0.  Rotation has to be defined relative to something else.

Comment: Ah you were fully right, thanks. My object was child of another one !